# Falling back to good default value when a CSS custom property is not set

Tags: css

I’m looking at using CSS custom properties as a theming solution for web components, but am uncertain about the best way to apply a custom property while at the same time preserving good default behavior if the custom property is left unspecified.

Example: I create a component whose shadow tree contains within it a `<button>` element, and want to let a user of the component theme the contained button’s foreground and background color according to the needs of their application’s branding. The DOM for this looks like:

```
<my-element>
  #shadow-root
    <style>
    button {
      background-color: var(--my-element-background-color);
      color: var(--my-element-color);
    }
    </style>
    <button>
      ...
    </button>
</my-element>
```

If someone doesn’t specify the implicated CSS custom properties, it’s reasonable for them to expect that the button shows its normal default appearance, but the above CSS is insufficient for this. The use of the `var()` overrides the browser’s default user agent stylesheet, so if the custom properties are unspecified, the color properties revert to their underlying default values *for all elements*, not the default values for `button` elements. So the buttons end up with `background-color: transparent`; for `color`, the default value varies by browser.

Those general default colors are unhelpful; what’s desired are the default color values for buttons. It’s possible to manually look up and replicate the default values from the user agent stylesheet. In this particular case, the default values are *most likely*  `buttonface` and `buttontext`. In which case, it would be possible to encode those as the default values for the custom properties.

```
button {
  background-color: var(--my-element-background-color, buttonface);
  color: var(--my-element-color, buttontext);
}
```

This is unfortunate. It’s a pain to look up the default value for every single property you want to expose via a custom property.

But a bigger problem is that this forces one to encode user agent styling into a component. That seems bad on several levels.

1. Browsers differ in their default styling.
2. While the above colors happen to have standard names, that approach can’t handle properties like `padding`, where the value has no name and the default value varies from browser to browser.
3. Even for properties with consistent default values, user agent styling could change in the future.

I'm guessing there are probably other reasons not to do this beyond the above.

I’m wondering if there’s anyway to write a CSS rule to the effect that a custom property is applied only if defined, and has no effect otherwise. I’m hoping to find a solution that relies only on custom properties as currently shipping, and doesn’t not rely on new proposals such as [@apply](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/).

Comment: Why not use classes?  The consumer of the theme can then use it as needed.

Comment: CSS class definitions defined outside on the page will not effect elements in a Shadow DOM subtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the ['revert' value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#default), which resolves to the *UA default*, not the initial value.  You can then use that as the fallback value.

(I don't think the keyword is supported widely yet, but that's the solution we've designed to this problem.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `revert`. While it's sad to see that this feature is not yet implemented in most browsers, it's very nice to know that at least the standards offer an answer here. Hopefully the other browsers will follow WebKit's lead here.